# foreach loop with SelectSingleNode always returns the first node

Tags: c#, xml, selectsinglenode, xml-documentation

I am trying to get the inner text of each domain node from an httpxml response.
I save the response to a string and load to `XmlDocument`. But using the code below or variations of it I either get "CorpDomainMyDomain aaaa" or just "CorpDomain aaaa".
I have tried various iterations of domain and domains and cannot get the domains individually.
I would have thought that

```
XmlNodeList elemList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//DAV:domains", nsmgr);
```

would have created a list of each of the Domain elements but it doesn't seem that way.

The xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
  <multistatus xmlns="DAV:">
   <response>

    <propstat>
        <prop>
            <domains>
                <domain logindefault="1" type="internal"><![CDATA[CorpDomain]]></domain>
                <domain type="internal"><![CDATA[MyDomain]]></domain>
            </domains>
        </prop>
    <status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</status>
    </propstat>
</response>
```

My code snippet

```
var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("DAV", "DAV:");
XmlNodeList elemList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//DAV:domains", nsmgr);

foreach (XmlNode node in elemList)
{
  strNode = node.SelectSingleNode("//DAV:domains", nsmgr).InnerText;
  responseString = strNode+" aaaa  ";
}

return responseString;
```

Comment: For clarity, what *exactly* is your expected output?

Comment: The expected output is CorpDomain aaaa MyDomain aaaa – at the end of the day I will be putting CorpDomain and MyDomain into a Combobox drop down on my main form. Currently just looking at getting the individual items

Comment: I could be going blind, but it appears that you are replacing the entire `responseString` on each iteration through the loop: `responseString = strNode+" aaaa  ";`. Are you sure you didn't mean e.g. `responseString = responseString + strNode + ...;`?

Comment: You are correct that I was over wrting the string. responseString += resolved it. This is just for the quick test. Final will be something like conbobox.Add.Item(responseString)

Comment: Glad you got that resolved. Voting to close as off-topic (typo). You may also want to refer to https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ if you come across a similar issue in the future.

Comment: @IainGalloway Hi Iain - even if the OP does fix the typo you've mentioned, his use of XPath to parse his document is incorrect, and results in the concatenated (and repeated, once the typo is fixed) output of `CorpDomainMyDomain aaaa`. I've clarified this in my answer - i.e. no, please don't close as a typo - incorrect root level pathing in a loop is a common issue in Xml document parsing and this might be of use to future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Even after you've fixed the `responseString += strNode` issue that Ian picked up on, When you loop through the `domain` elements under the `domains` parent, you shouldn't again use `//` - that will reset the context to the root of the document.

e.g. if your XmlDocument looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
  <multistatus xmlns="DAV:">
   <response>
    <propstat>
        <prop>
            <domains>
                <domain logindefault="1" type="internal">domains1-domain1</domain>
                <domain type="internal">domains1-domain2</domain>
            </domains>
        </prop>
        <prop>
            <domains>
                <domain logindefault="1" type="internal">domains2-domain1</domain>
                <domain type="internal">domains2-domain2</domain>
            </domains>
        </prop>
       <status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</status>
    </propstat>
   </response>
</multistatus>
```

your code would in fact scrape the combined text nodes of all child nodes of just the first `domains` element, i.e. something like (where `aaaa` is your delimiter):

> domains1-domain1 aaaa domains1-domain2 aaaa

Instead, you should just provide the relative pathing from parent to child, i.e. just `domain` in your case. Assuming that there are N `domains` parent elements each with M `domain` child elements, if you stop at the parent nodes, you will need a second level of iteration through the child nodes:

```
var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("DAV", "DAV:");
XmlNodeList elemList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//DAV:domains", nsmgr);
foreach (var domains in elemList)
{
    foreach (var domain in domains.SelectNodes("DAV:domain", nsmgr))
    {
       strNode = domain.InnerText;
       responseString = strNode+" aaaa  ";
    }
}
return responseString;
```

But if you don't need to retain a reference to the parent for other purposes, you could also do this in one step by flattening out the child nodes directly. For large xml documents with many nodes, it would also be a good idea to avoid the string concatenation problem, e.g. with a `StringBuilder`:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (XmlNode node in xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//DAV:domains/DAV:domain", nsmgr))
{
    var strNode = node.InnerText;
    sb.Append(strNode); // do the same for delimiter 
}
// use sb.ToString() here.
```

Comment: Sorry but I had tried that and it only returnsthe first domain node not the 2nd. result is
CorpDomain aaaa

Comment: For the 2nd example not using sb the result is 
MyDomain aaaa so this is writing the 2nd node but not the first or it may be overwriting the first will test that further.

Comment: @Hammertime apologies - I wasn't paying enough attention to detail in my first answer - it would have continually selected the first child `domain` in each `domains` tree. I've fixed. The second approach should work irrespective - just make sure you're initializing the StringBuilder outside of the loops.

Comment: In the 2nd approach, you can go directly to `//DAV:domain`, provided there aren't any other elements named `domain` underneath different parents which you need to exclude.

Comment: Thank you, I have gone with the 2nd approach for now. Now onto understanding more about LING to XML for reading bits of a 5000 line dirty XML file and extracting some of the childnodes of the parent node based on a known child node element.